# Loading from csv and storing in HashMap with key containing multiple values

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

I have a hashmap that is storing values from a csv file. The file consists of three columns: TEMPLATE_NAME, PARAM_1, PARAM_2

I've been trying to use TEMPLATE_NAME as the key and PARM_1, PARAM_2 as the values for each row. The problem is that there may be many TEMPLATE_NAME with a different mix of params. My requirement specifies that a list of TEMPLATE_NAMES should be displayed when a PARAM_1 and PARAM_2 is selected.

I know that a hashmap cannot have duplicate keys so the hashmap is only creating one TEMPLATE_NAME key with values but ignoring the duplicates. How do I resolve this?

```
private void load() throws IOException{
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader();
        List<List<String>> rows = reader.parse(csvFile);

    for (int i = 1 ; i<rows.size() ; i++){
        List<String> columns = rows.get(i);
        String templateName = columns.get(TEMPLATE_NAME);

        OnConfig config = entries.get(templateName);
        if (config == null){
            config = new OnConfig(templateName);
            entries.put(templateName, config);
        }

        config.put(columns.get(PARAM_1), columns.get(PARAM_2));

    }
}



public class OnConfig {

    private final String templateName;

    private final HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();

    public OnConfig(String templateName){
        this.templateName= templateName;
    }

    public void put(String param1, String param2){
        attributes.put(param1, param2);
    }

    public String get(String param1){
        return attributes.get(param1);
    }

    public String getTemplateName() {
        return templateName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Template Name: %s, Number of Attributes: %s", getTemplateName(), attributes.value());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that there may be many TEMPLATE_NAME with a different mix of params.

1. Create a new class representing TEMPLATE_NAMES and containing a List or Map of PARM_1, PARAM_2
2. Use a nested data structure. For instance, Nest a Map inside a Map: the outer keys are the TEMPLATE_NAMES, and inner key is PARAM_1